# Having trouble with Simon says game using python and tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

So I'm coding this classic memory game called simon says. I have everything working, up until the actual turn based part when the computer plays a pattern, and then the user repeats the pattern. I have a function called pattern.flash() which flashes the pattern. I also have functions that will enable and disable the bindings that allow the user to click the squares. I need help figuring out how to actually finish the game. Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *
import time
import random

global pattern_list
pattern_list = []
global user_list
user_list = []
comp_pattern_count = 0
user_pattern_count = []

def flash_blue_auto(index = 0):
    global comp_pattern_count
    flashing_colours = ["blue", "darkblue"]
    try:
        w.itemconfigure(blue_rectangle, fill=flashing_colours[index])
        window.after(100, flash_blue_auto, index + 1)

    except IndexError:
        comp_pattern_count += 1
        pass

def flash_red_auto(index = 0):
    global comp_pattern_count
    flashing_colours = ["red", "darkred"]
    try:
        w.itemconfigure(red_rectangle, fill=flashing_colours[index])
        window.after(100, flash_red_auto, index + 1)

    except IndexError:
        comp_pattern_count += 1
        pass

def flash_yellow_auto(index = 0):
    global comp_pattern_count
    flashing_colours = ["goldenrod", "darkgoldenrod"]

    try:
        w.itemconfigure(yellow_rectangle, fill=flashing_colours[index])
        window.after(100, flash_yellow_auto, index + 1)

    except IndexError:
        comp_pattern_count += 1
        pass

def flash_green_auto(index = 0):
    global comp_pattern_count
    flashing_colours = ["green", "darkgreen"]
    try:
        w.itemconfigure(green_rectangle, fill=flashing_colours[index])
        window.after(100, flash_green_auto, index + 1)

    except IndexError:
        comp_pattern_count += 1
        pass


def flash_blue(event, index = 0):
    global user_pattern_count
    flashing_colours = ["blue", "darkblue"]
    try:
        w.itemconfigure(blue_rectangle, fill=flashing_colours[index])
        window.after(100, flash_blue, "dummy", index + 1)
        user_list.append(1)

    except IndexError:
        pass

def flash_red(event, index = 0):
    global user_pattern_count
    flashing_colours = ["red", "darkred"]
    try:
        w.itemconfigure(red_rectangle, fill=flashing_colours[index])
        window.after(100, flash_red, "dummy", index + 1)
        user_list.append(2)

    except IndexError:
        pass

def flash_yellow(event, index = 0):
    global user_pattern_count
    flashing_colours = ["goldenrod", "darkgoldenrod"]
    try:
        w.itemconfigure(yellow_rectangle, fill=flashing_colours[index])
        window.after(100, flash_yellow, "dummy", index + 1)
        user_list.append(3)

    except IndexError:
        pass

def flash_green(event, index = 0):
    global user_pattern_count
    flashing_colours = ["green", "darkgreen"]
    try:
        w.itemconfigure(green_rectangle, fill=flashing_colours[index])
        window.after(100, flash_green, "dummy", index + 1)
        user_list.append(4)

    except IndexError:
        pass


def remove_click():
    w.tag_unbind(blue_rectangle, "<ButtonPress-1>")
    w.tag_unbind(red_rectangle, "<ButtonPress-1>")
    w.tag_unbind(yellow_rectangle, "<ButtonPress-1>")
    w.tag_unbind(green_rectangle, "<ButtonPress-1>")

def add_click():
    w.tag_bind(blue_rectangle, "<ButtonPress-1>", flash_blue)
    w.tag_bind(red_rectangle, "<ButtonPress-1>", flash_red)
    w.tag_bind(yellow_rectangle, "<ButtonPress-1>", flash_yellow)
    w.tag_bind(green_rectangle, "<ButtonPress-1>", flash_green)


def pattern_flash():
    pattern_list.append(random.randint(1, 4))

    for x in pattern_list:

        if x == 1:
            window.after(500, lambda: flash_blue_auto(index=0))
            window.update()
            time.sleep(0.5)

        elif x == 2:
            window.after(500, lambda: flash_red_auto(index=0))
            window.update()
            time.sleep(0.5)

        elif x == 3:
            window.after(500, lambda: flash_yellow_auto(index=0))
            window.update()
            time.sleep(0.5)

        else:
            window.after(500, lambda: flash_green_auto(index=0))
            window.update()
            time.sleep(0.5)




window = Tk()

w = Canvas(window, width=1366, height=766)
w.configure(background = "black")
w.pack()

blue_rectangle = w.create_rectangle(483, 480, 683, 680, fill="darkblue")
red_rectangle = w.create_rectangle(683, 480, 883, 680, fill="darkred")
yellow_rectangle = w.create_rectangle(483, 280, 683, 480, fill="darkgoldenrod")
green_rectangle = w.create_rectangle(683, 280, 883, 480, fill="darkgreen")

#This is the part where I get lost

pattern_flash()
add_click()
```

I want to flash the pattern, enable the bindings, wait for the user to click the pattern, then when they have clicked whatever squares the same amount of times as the length of the pattern list, the bindings are disabled. Then, if they get the pattern right, the program is looped, and if they don't get it right, the program is stopped. Any help is greatly appreciated, and very soon! This assignment is due tomorrow!

Comment: for one, you don't need `flash_yellow`, `flash_green`, etc. They are all identical except the color, so just pass the color in as a parameter.

Comment: Hey could you show me the code of how to do that?

Comment: Also, using `global` in the global scope (outside of functions and classes) is pointless.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please look at [mcve], [no mcve](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/), [sscce](http://www.sscce.org/) and [Jon Skeet's writing the perfect question]( Jon Skeet's writing the perfect question.) to see how to improve your question.